# Android fragment navigation via replacable fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment

I'm very new to fragment and I'm trying to achieve a certain type of objective here.

Consider this scenario : I have three fragments F1, F2 and F3. Now when I move from F1 to F2 there is no problem. Now the issue is, there is a button in F2 which when clicked, replaces F2 with F3. Which means, F3 should 'take the place' of F2 without creating a new item in the backstack. The purpose behind that is, when the back button is pressed when the user is either in F2 or F3, it should redirect back to F1.

I think I can do that however all sort of mess arises when pressing the back button. Once again, what I want is, when either of F2 or F3 is active, the back button should lead me back to F1.

[image]

The code which I'm using to **go from F1 to F2** is :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment fr = new FragmentTwo();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code which I'm using to **replace F2 with F3** is :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment fr = new FragmentThree();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code which I'm using to **replace F3 with F2** is :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment fr = new FragmentTwo();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Any suggestions and tips will be really appreciated.

**EDIT :**
**I have uploaded the source of my project here :**

https://ufile.io/4e665

Regards

Comment: `I think I can do that however all sort of mess arises when pressing the back button`. What kind of mess??

Comment: @VivekMishra : Well, I can go from F1 to F2 and back to F1 without any trouble. But when I go from F1 to F2 and then switch F2 with F3 and try the back button, it doesn't revert to F1. Instead, it stays at F3. Now if I press the back button a second time, the app closes. So basically the problem starts when I try to switch from F2 to F3. Somehow, the backstack gets screwed up or something..

Comment: Please check the original post for a link to my project. Tq

Comment: Using fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); when replace fragments between F2 and F3 may be useful.

Comment: ^ I tried that. Didn't work. And if you think logically, it should not work. Let's say I switch between F2 and F3 ten times. Then if addToBackStack is there, there will be ten entries of switching between the two fragment and pressing back button will only roll back these entries one by one. In other word, to get to F1, I'll have to keep tapping back ten times.

Comment: I a trying now your code. If i have a suggestion i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this may not be the best approach but for now it solves my problem. I tried this approach when switching from F2 to F3 and back from F3 to F2 and surprisingly it worked (as in the back buttons are functioning as it should) :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment fr = new FragmentThree();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also, please note that my onBackPressed is implemented like this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        System.out.println("getBackStackEntryCount() VALUE : " + count);

        if (count == 0) {

            System.out.println("onBackPressed() CALLED");
            super.onBackPressed();
            //additional code
        } else {

            System.out.println("popBackStack() CALLED");
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**From activity to F1**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fr = new FragmentOne();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**From F1 to F2**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fr = new FragmentTwo();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Between other fragments**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fr = new FragmentThree();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fr = new FragmentTwo();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Are you sure about the above approach? I tried it and it did not work and rightfully so, it should not work because in none of the block above, you used addToBackStack. So how will the app reverse to the previous fragment? I tried you code exactly like how you detailed it above however as I explained, in any screen, when back button is pressed, the whole app closes because there is no single record of the transaction (not a single addToBackStack is used)...

Comment: Sorry, i forgot this line 'fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("any tag for fragment 1");'. This line in from f1 to f2 block before replace.